# LINQ- select column with most frequent value

Tags: linq, join, group-by

I have a database that keep track of books and borrowers. I want to answer this question with linq: what is the most borrowed books?(top 5 for example).
in the Book table we have : Id , Title and in the table loan We have : Id, Book Id

I use the code bellow but it return the key and I need the Title of books

```cs
  var MostBorrowedBook = _context.Books.Join(_context.Loans, 
  y=> y.Id,
 x=>  x.BookId,
 (y,x)=> y)
.GroupBy(q=> q.Id)
.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Count())
.Take(5)
.Select(q=>q.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Add to grouping key `Title`.

Comment: I use this one : var mostBorrowedBook = await _context.Books.Join(_context.Loans, y=> y.Id, x=>x.BookId, (y,x)=> y).
        GroupBy(q=> new{q.Id , q.Title} ).OrderByDescending(q=>q.Count()).Take(5).ToListAsync(); but I have this error : system.InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.

Comment: You forgot `.Select(q=>q.Key)`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var mostBorrowedBook =  _context.Books.Join(_context.Loans, y => y.Id, x => x.BookId, (y, x) => y)
    .GroupBy(q => new{q.Id, q.Title})
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.Count())
    .Take(5)
    .Select(g => g.Key.Title)
    .ToList();
```